# How to replace nested span to div element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to check whether the given `htmlData` has nested(parent,child not siblings) `span` elements with attribute name `data-fact` or not.

if it does then replace it with `span` to `div` with `class='inline-span'` pass all the attributes with it.
else just return the `htmlData`

```
var htmlData = `<p style="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin: 0pt 0;" xvid="f5ea22ec52553bc61525766b631e126f">
  <span xvid="2b80c95cd4b851345ba4c3fe6937d30b" conceptid="619959bc062c677faebd7a6f" xbrlid="rr:ProspectusDate" class="manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b55">
    <span xvid="ca5635a4e4de332d7dc3036a68e57009" class="wrapped manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b57">November 1, 2021</span>
  </span>
</p>
`
replaceTags(htmlData)
```

```
function replaceTags (htmlData) {
var $elm = $(htmlData).find("span[data-fact]");
var $nestedElm = $elm.children().length > 1;
        if($nestedElm){
            htmlData = htmlData.replace(/<span/g, '<div class="inline-span" ');
            htmlData = htmlData.replace(/<\/span>/g, '<\/div>');
        }else{
            return htmlData;
        }
    },
```

The output `htmlData` i want is something like this

```
<p style="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin: 0pt 0;" xvid="f5ea22ec52553bc61525766b631e126f">
  <div class='inline-span' xvid="2b80c95cd4b851345ba4c3fe6937d30b" conceptid="619959bc062c677faebd7a6f" xbrlid="rr:ProspectusDate" class="manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b55">
    <div  class='inline-span' xvid="ca5635a4e4de332d7dc3036a68e57009" class="wrapped manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b57">November 1, 2021</div>
  </div>
</p>
```

Here i'm not able to find is the `span` element is nested or not and then the conversion of how can i pass the `class='inline-span'` with all the previous attributes to the `div`.

PS: answer i want is in JQuery

Comment: The output html data you want is invalid html and won't render in any browser (at least not in the way you would expect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typically a bad idea to do string replacement to change HTML. You should instead use the tools of jquery to manipulate the DOM. Which is safer and less error prone.

```js
const replaceTags = ($tagToReplace) => { 
  // create a copy of the htmlData
  const $cloned = $tagToReplace.clone();
  
  // While there are still more span's in the p
  while ($cloned.find('span[data-fact]').length > 0) {
    // get the next span to replace with a div
    const $span = $($cloned.find('span[data-fact]')[0]);

    // create the new div
    const $newDiv = $('<div>');
    // copy the span's html into the div
    $newDiv.html($span.html());

    // For each attribute in the span ...
    $.each($span[0].attributes, (_ , attr) => {
      // ... set the new div to have the span's attribute.
      $newDiv.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
    });

    // new div needs 'inline-span' property.
    $newDiv.addClass('inline-span');

    // finally replace the span with the new div
    $span.replaceWith($newDiv);
  }
  
  return $cloned;
}

// select tag to replace
const $tagToReplace = $('p');
// get the new cloned tag
const $newHtmlData = replaceTags($tagToReplace);

// add the cloned to the body
$('body').append($newHtmlData);
// print that new elements html
console.log($newHtmlData[0].outerHTML);
```

```css
p {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

span[data-fact] {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}

div[data-fact] { 
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin: 0pt 0;" xvid="f5ea22ec52553bc61525766b631e126f">
  <span xvid="2b80c95cd4b851345ba4c3fe6937d30b" conceptid="619959bc062c677faebd7a6f" xbrlid="rr:ProspectusDate" class="manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b55">
    <span xvid="ca5635a4e4de332d7dc3036a68e57009" class="wrapped manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b57">November 1, 2021</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

NOTE: it is invalid HTML to have `div` tag inside `p` so one should probably replace the `p` tag too.

Comment: I have updated to to select on attribute `span[data-fact]`

Comment: I have updated it so that new cloned object is created. You can insert it directly in the DOM or inspect its HTML.

Comment: Thank you this worked and now i get what you meant for invalid HTML, yeah it doesn't work as expected but the conversion works.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> var htmlData = `<p style="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin: 0pt 0;" xvid="f5ea22ec52553bc61525766b631e126f">
  <span xvid="2b80c95cd4b851345ba4c3fe6937d30b" conceptid="619959bc062c677faebd7a6f" xbrlid="rr:ProspectusDate" class="manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b55">
    <span xvid="ca5635a4e4de332d7dc3036a68e57009" class="wrapped manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b57">November 1, 2021</span>
  </span>
</p>
`
console.log(replaceTags(htmlData, "span span[data-fact]","div"));

//a very handy function from Matt Basta to rplace tag names cannot be done on the fly without such functions
 function replaceElement(source, newType) { 
    // Create the document fragment 
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment(); 
    // Fill it with what's in the source element 
    while (source.firstChild) { 
      frag.appendChild(source.firstChild); 
    } 
    // Create the new element 
    const newElem = document.createElement(newType); 
    // Empty the document fragment into it 
    newElem.appendChild(frag); 
    // Replace the source element with the new element on the page 
    source.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, source); 
  }
//we now use our function as warper on above function.
function replaceTags (htmlData,whatToChange,withWhat) {
var fragment = document.createElement('just');
  fragment.innerHTML=htmlData;
  var found = fragment.querySelector(whatToChange);
  if(found){
replaceElement(fragment.querySelector(whatToChange), withWhat);} 
return fragment.innerHTML;
        
   }
    
    </script>
```

Getting as to what you want here is more logical solution that mixes bunch of search logics to do the job. Not perfect but its close

Comment: Can you check what if there is no nested span element does it it still change it?
because if so then i only need this work with `data-fact` and it's nested `span` element.

Comment: Assumtion was from your own work up that determination is made whether to make chnages or not based on data-fact attribute. if it is present in the string make the chnages on span tag else business as usual. I have given an example if darta-fact is present but no span tag then nothing witll change. <span + data-fact needs to present in string to make the chnage happen.

Comment: I checked what you did, but instead of thinking if it's not span then it will just check the condition and goes of the loop, but your first example had nested `span` try removing one  inner `span` and see what it give you.
i only want these two coniditions to satisfy it should have a `data-fact` and it is nested element.

Comment: pls check updated answer it is more complex but will give you all the freedom you need to do what you need regardless. point being we will not do regex as blind shooting but run logic through selector and then chnage that with programming. if selectro found good else business as usuall, how ever you still have to fine tune it to keep what you wnat and let go what you dont want

Comment: Thank you will check if it works in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes related to Find in HTML element and in replace jquery code here is a working demo hope it will be helpful for you.

you can direcatly replace all  html with   like

```
htmlData = htmlData.replace($factElem[0].outerHTML, 'div html');
```

using `$factElem[0].outerHTML` you can find element containing **[data-fact]** html.
yes you can check only using data-fact and replace it with div there is no span needed

I updated Code Please check now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                var htmlData = '<p style="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin: 0pt 0;" xvid="f5ea22ec52553bc61525766b631e126f"><span xvid="2b80c95cd4b851345ba4c3fe6937d30b" conceptid="619959bc062c677faebd7a6f" xbrlid="rr:ProspectusDate" class="manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b55"><span xvid="ca5635a4e4de332d7dc3036a68e57009" class="wrapped manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b57">November 1, 2021</span></span></p>'
                replaceTags(htmlData);
            });
        });
        function replaceTags(htmlData) {
            var $factElem = $(htmlData).find('[data-fact]');
            if ($factElem) {
                htmlData = htmlData.replace($factElem[0].outerHTML, '<div class="inline-span" xvid="2b80c95cd4b851345ba4c3fe6937d30b" conceptid="619959bc062c677faebd7a6f" xbrlid="rr:ProspectusDate" class="manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b55"><div class="inline-span" xvid="ca5635a4e4de332d7dc3036a68e57009" class="wrapped manual-map" data-fact="619959c0062c677faebd7b57">November 1, 2021</div></div>');
                $("#append").empty().append(htmlData);

                alert(htmlData);
            } else {
                $("#append").empty().append(htmlData);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="append"></div>
    <button>Click me to Replace!!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SDP please check!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does help but i'm not looking to change the `div` that way more generic with regex which i wanted.